# Fill column based on a reference table

Tags: excel, vba

General purpose of my project is to copy data from a file I get daily into another file with specific formatting and correcting the addresses (so I can create a serial letter).

I have the table with streetnames (in Col I)
[image]

that needs to be augmented with the postal code (in Col K) based on a reference table in a separate workbook.
[image]

I tried adding [this code](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/vba-macro-fill-cells-based-on-values-in-a-reference-table.743351/) I found for a somewhat similar question into my (otherwise working):

```vb
Dim wsziel As Worksheet
Set wsziel = Workbooks("VBA_Tagesliste.xlsx").Worksheets("Adressen") 
    
Workbooks.Open Filename:="[...]\TEST VBA\street_ref.xls"
Dim wsstreetref As Worksheet
Set wsstreetref = Workbooks("street_ref.xls").Worksheets("Abgleich")

Dim rngPLZ As Range, rngFillPLZ As Range, c As Range, fLoc As Range, comb As Range, fAdr As String

Set rngPLZ = wsstreetref.Range("A2:A1222") 'Reference
Set rngFillPLZ = wsziel.Range(":I3") 'Fill

For Each c In rngPLZ
    If c <> "" Then
        Set fLoc = rngFillPLZ.Find(c.Value & "*", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        
        If Not fLoc Is Nothing Then
            fAdr = fLoc.Address
            Do
                Set comb = Union(c.Offset(0, -2), c.Offset(0, -1))
                comb.Copy fLoc.Offset(0, -2)
                fLoc.Value = c.Value
                Set fLoc = rngFillPLZ.FindNext(fLoc)
            Loop While fAdr <> fLoc.Address
        End If
    End If
Next
```

I do not fully understand what the code in the Do is doing, so I had to do a bit trial and error which didn't work.

Another complication (which I'd like to put on hold until I get a grasp on how to solve this one) is that there are some streets where I need to incorporate the house number (Col J) into the mix, as the reference looks like this
[image]

(the empty postcodes is a simplification, because the tend to go 1,2,3,5 in one and 4,6,7,8... in the next post code - My plan was to colour those fields instead and later solve them manually as they shouldn't be too many).

Comment: Why do you need VBA for this? It seems doable with just a formula.

Comment: I get a new set of data every morning and need to create a new adress list for the letters out of it, which includes shifting columns around, filling in dates and formatting everything. With the VBA code i managed to cut down half an hour of work into simply copying the code into the VBA editor and letting it run. Also, I want to make it as fool proof as possible since every other week there is another colleague doing this. 
But maybe I could fill the formula in an unused column and then work with copy/pastevalue - but I honestly don't even know which catchword i should google for...

Comment: Maybe SUMIFS and a wildcard `*`... and you can use VBA to insert a formula.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally clicked enter and then edited - Just had that same thought, but i don't even know which catchphrase to google for that. ("Join many-to-many" as it was in ArcGIS doesn't get me to useable results...)

Answer (score 0):

So, BigBens question actually pushed me in the right direction.
I didn't quite understand the SUMFIS function, but in the quest to do so I stumbled upon INDEX and MATCH, which worked perfectly after putting my street references in another worksheet in the document.

```
[...]
Set rngToFill = wsziel.Range("BA3:BA" & LastRowZiel) 'PLZ-Lookup in Hilfszeile
rngToFill.FormulaLocal = "=INDEX(streetref!B1:B1223; VERGLEICH(I3; streetref!A1:A1222; 0))" 'PLZ-Lookup aus zweiter Tabelle
Set source = wsziel.Range("BA3:BA" & LastRowZiel)
Set target = wsziel.Range("K3")
source.Copy
target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
[...]
```

At least for the single-postcode-streets, but I'm optimistic I'll solve the multi-streets today. :)